# Display Inset Border around Gravatar like on Twitter

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, gravatar

I want my gravatar image on my website project to be displayed like this:

[image]

How to achieve in CSS?

**Update**

Let me describe what I want:

- A HTML Image Tag, 40 pixels long sides
- A CSS Class:

  - Makes Rounded Borders around all 4 edges
  - Throws a shadow inside the image (inset shadow), but very subtle

For demo, click on https://twitter.com, log in, and see avatar in upper right corner.

Comment: Like what? What do you exactly mean? Where's the current code?

Answer (score 3):

If you use the developer tools, you can see that Twitter uses the `::before` pseudo-selector there to add an inwards `box-shadow` to the avatar, here's a demo which I've created for you: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/75dcuc51/4/)**.

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="twitterimage"><img src="// image URL" /></a>
```

CSS:

```
#twitterimage, #twitterimage img {
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
#twitterimage:before {
    display: block;
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

Comment: Edited your fiddle and question to make the images borders round as well.

Comment: Can you share the link to the fiddle where you've added the new picture?

Comment: You've missed `border-radius` on the image itself - http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/75dcuc51/6/

Comment: Now it is working in offline my test. However Twitter Profiles Images are not displayed in the fiddle. Fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nottinhill/LkxLuup3/1/

Comment: By the way, I noticed `moz-border-radius` is no longer needed for  Firefox to display this correctly. Have browser-specific options become obsolete finally?

Answer (score 1):

Rightclick on Image -> Inspect Element then look at the Style/Css tab.

I think this will do (found with inspect element):

```
img.avatar {
    border-color: rgb(102, 117, 127);
    border-image-width: 1px;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Edit: Here's a copy of my computed style panel **

```
font-family "Helvetica Neue",​Helvetica,​Arial,​sans-serif
font-size   13px
font-weight 500
color   rgb(102,​ 117,​ 127)
line-height 13px
text-align  left
width   32px
height  32px
border-top-width    0px
border-right-width  0px
border-bottom-width 0px
border-left-width   0px
border-top-color    rgb(102,​ 117,​ 127)
border-right-color  rgb(102,​ 117,​ 127)
border-bottom-color rgb(102,​ 117,​ 127)
border-left-color   rgb(102,​ 117,​ 127)
border-top-style    none
border-right-style  none
border-bottom-style none
border-left-style   none
border-image    
border-top-left-radius  4px
border-top-right-radius 4px
border-bottom-left-radius   4px
border-bottom-right-radius  4px
border-image-outset 0 0 0 0
border-image-repeat stretch stretch
border-image-slice  100% 100% 100% 100%
border-image-source none
border-image-width  1 1 1 1
cursor  pointer
list-style-image    none
list-style-position outside
list-style-type none
```